# How can I parse JSON using the data parameter in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rest

I am making a web application using Jersey and JQuery for client-side. 
I have the following URL that returns a JSON string:

```
http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/1
```

returns:

```
 {"author":"Joe","created":"2015-07-28T22:33:34.667","id":1,"message":"Hello World"}
```

when typed into the browser.

Now I am attempting to get this data client-side using the following JQuery functions:

```
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages";

$(function() {


$('#btnRegister').click(function() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    addMessage();
});

function addMessage() {

    var url = rootURL;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootURL +"/1",
        dataType: "json", // data type of response
        success: (function(data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert('ID: ' + obj.id);

        })
    });
}
```

});

EDIT: When the "btnRegister" is pressed nothing is displayed at all

which just doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is some unwanted `$` wrapping in success callback function, also there is no need to parse the response as you set `dataType:'json'`. For better understanding of **[`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** read documentation **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#btnRegister').click(function() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    addMessage();
  });

  function addMessage() {

    var url = rootURL;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: rootURL + "/1",
      dataType: "json", // data type of response
      success: function(data) {
        //----^----------- remove the $ sign
        alert('ID: ' + data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

You can access the value using `obj.prop` or `obj['prop']`

```js
var obj= {"author":"Joe","created":"2015-07-28T22:33:34.667","id":1,"message":"Hello World"};

alert(obj.author);
alert(obj['author']);
```

Comment: Ok I have done that... as I have indicated in the EDIT. Now nothing at all pops up? - Nevermind!